# Why DOCUMENT_ROOT is different than realpath('.') on remote server

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

with

```
echo realpath('.').'<br>';
echo dirname(__FILE__).'<br>';
echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'<br>';
echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF].'<br>'; 
echo getcwd();
```

I get always

```
/services2/webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br/mydomain.com/public
```

but in phpinfo DOCUMENT_ROOT is

```
/services/webpages/l/i/mydomain.com/public
```

because of that I'm having hard times with .htaccess in conjunction with Zend Framework.

On my local I'm able to make it work. But on the provider host I could not grasp the magic yet.

EDT: I put `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` on the index file but got this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'parse_ini_file(/services2/webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br/mydomain.com/public/v0.2b/application/configs/appkeys.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory parse_ini_file(/services2/webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br/mydomain.com/public/v0.2b/application/configs/appkeys.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /services2/webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br/mydomain.com/public/v0.2b/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php:181 Stack trace: #0 /services2/webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br/mydomain.com/public/v0.2b/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php(201): Zend_Config_Ini->_parseIniFile('/services2/webp...') #1 /services2/webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br/mydomain.com/public/v0.2b/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php(125): Zend_Config_ in /services2/webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br/mydomain.com/public/v0.2b/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php on line 181

EDT:
thats the one:

```
$appkeys = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/appkeys.ini');
```

and APPLICATION_PATH is defined by

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

Comment: Do DOCUMENT_ROOT actually work in present form?

Comment: yes. It's just the way it works. Don't know why Zend try the realpath and why the error also.

Comment: could you please add the actual code that produces this very error? You know, it's hard as hell to foresee it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\n";
```

And read [this](http://php.net/realpath)

Comment: I got the point. thanks! But what about the address translations discrepancies made by zend? or could I force htaccess/zend to give always just one of those? The point is that PHP will just see /services/webpages/l/i/mydomain.com/public. The realpath just throw a file not found on php.

Comment: if your write this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` than ZF must use this address always, in .htaccess your can`t modify DOCUMENT_ROOT but in server config can!

Comment: a lot of time I dont touch php. I'm prety lost on that. Just added a EDT with the error I still having.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that some of the directories in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` are actually [symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink) to other directories - to quote [the documentation](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php),

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to '/./', '/../' and extra '/' characters in the input path and return the canonicalized absolute pathname.

Therefore, if (for example), `/services/webpages/l` is a directory, and `/services/webpages/l/i` is a symlink pointing to `/services2/webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br`, both `/services2/webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br/mydomain.com/public` and `/services/webpages/l/i/mydomain.com/public` will get you to the same directory, but realpath() will always return the former.

```
/services
 + webpages
 | - util
 |   - i
 |     - g 
 |       - gg8375620.provider.com.br
 |         - mydomain.com
 |           - public
 + l
   - i -> ../webpages/util/i/g/gg8375620.provider.com.br/
```

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain? Although symlinks may seem like magic to you, I assure you that they work, and that realpath() will dereference them.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. We know from what was states before that it's a Symlink or Alias (my guess). Just trying to not start the discussion from a step back. The only commom part in those paths are the end: mydomain.com/public

Comment: @Ruben Trancoso: I don't see anyone mentioning anything about symlinks in this question; if you already knew this, it would be useful to include it in the question. Also, if it's a symlink, then realpath() will always dereference it, therefore its input won't ever match the output.

Comment: azat post just mentioned that before.

Comment: I must be blind then, this is the post in its entirety: "Try this:
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\n";

And read this (link to documentation)" Eh, forget it. I'm not going to argue with you about who said what and who didn't. Piskvor out.

Comment: There's a link to the same documentation you put. Nothing wrong with that. None will lose nothing. I was justing priorizing the discussion. Sorry. I didn't mean to underestimate you.

Answer (score 1):

document_root is coming from your web server configuration file that is why is it different from realpath function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, DOCUMENT_ROOT environment variable is just set to wrong value.
If you have no control of this server, you can't fix it yourself.
Either ask support to fix or find a way to avoid this variable use

As it seems as ZF problem, I think it's easy to solve.
I never used that framework but I am sure it has single entry point or some config file.
So, you can easily fake DOCUMENT ROOT by setting something like this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../');
```

where '/../' represents relative path from such an entry point to the actual document root

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT is just what PHP can reach. The realpath is what it cant. But zend is trying to go to the realpath.

Comment: maybe, the realpath is been taken as a relative to the ROOT and the error shows that realtive path over the ROOT that canot be found.

Answer (score 0):

echo realpath(dirname(**FILE**));

this should be helpful. on this link http://www.tech99.us/finding-absolute-path-in-php/you can find details for using these functions. each function used in above line works with php4 and php5.